# Is it possible to create overlapping, clickable, triangular images with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, polygon, imagemap

I'm trying to create clickable triangular images that overlap using CSS and HTML. Here is an example image showing the layout:

[image: Overlapping Triangle Divs]

The divs need to contain images and need to be clickable links. I have tried a few different techniques to achieve this and thus far haven't found one that works. I have tried:

- Border-based triangular divs containing  tags and  tags (this does not create a truly triangular clickable area)
- Triangle image maps overlapping each other (this fails because the overlapping section of the top image map obscures the clickable area of the one below)
- SVG with an internal  xlink tag containing a polygon and an image (Wasn't able to make a clickable triangle that also contains an image)

Is this possible and if so does anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: Probably best is to just use a SVG and add IDs to each triangle and then use Javascript to attach click handlers to each? Let me know how that works

Comment: @CptChix With that technique would I just include the image in the SVG or would I need to overlay an image on top of the SVG while setting an event handler for just the SVG element?

Comment: Just inline the SVG. Give me the SVG code. I can make you a working examplke

Comment: https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dakFi

Comment: @Temani Afif Thank you, somehow I missed this one in all my searching. Solved my problem!